# How to connect to MongoDB on Docker from another express server container. MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose, mongo-express

I'm new to Docker and struggling to use it with mongo and mongo_express. I found many StackOverflow posts about this issue, but none of them solved the problem I'm dealing with.

I'm making a website that requires a user login function, and usernames and passwords are supposed to be stored on mongod. However, it seems like my database server (node.js express) is not connected to the database that is located in another container. I think this is the reason why I receive this (MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND MongoDB).

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file, and express is node server, mongo is database, and mongo_express is a database management tool.

```
services:
  express:
    container_name: video-express
    image: video-express:latest
    build:
      context: ./express
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.express
    ports:
      - "13000:3000"
    volumes:
      - video_express_node:/app/node_modules
      - ./express:/app
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - default

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: q-cards-db
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/database
    networks:
      - default
      - mongo-express

  mongo_express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongo
      # ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: admin
      # ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: Password1
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - mongo-express

  dev:
    container_name: video-dev

    image: video-dev:latest

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - "15173:5173"

    volumes:
      - video_dev_node_modules:/app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - express

    tty: true

    stdin_open: true

    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
  mongo-express:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  video_dev_node_modules:
  video_express_node:
```

And here is the connection part of server.js file.

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://root:pass@mongodb:27017/videoUserDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
```

If I connect to http://0.0.0.0:8081/db/admin/, I can open mongo-express page, so I assume the problem is the connection between server.js and mongod.

These are error messages I see now. There are some I cannot understand, but if you can identify the problem by these, that would be great.

```
(node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is 

deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
video-management-mongo_express-1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://root:password@mongo:27017/"
video-management-mongo_express-1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:27017
video-management-mongo_express-1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
video-management-mongo_express-1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
video-management-mongo_express-1  | }]
video-management-mongo_express-1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)


video-management-mongo_express-1  | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
video-management-mongo_express-1  | Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
video-express                     | /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824
video-express                     |   const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
video-express                     |                                ^
video-express                     |
video-express                     | MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
video-express                     |     at Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:824:32)
video-express                     |     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:381:10
video-express                     |     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:41:5
video-express                     |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
video-express                     |     at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:40:10)
video-express                     |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1234:10)
video-express                     |     at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:380:20)
video-express                     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:50:10)
video-express                     |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
video-express                     |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10) {
video-express                     |   reason: TopologyDescription {
video-express                     |     type: 'Unknown',
video-express                     |     servers: Map(1) {
video-express                     |       'mongodb:27017' => ServerDescription {
video-express                     |         address: 'mongodb:27017',
video-express                     |         type: 'Unknown',
```

Comment: It looks like you've named your database container `mongo`, not `mongodb`, and you should use that name as the host name for the connection.  (YAML is extremely sensitive to differences in indentation, so please double-check the indentation of what you've included in the question.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I fixed the indentation of yaml file.

Comment: As for the container name, I think just mongo is right because all the examples I see only use mongo rather than mongod. This is because the name of docker image is mongo. Is there another possible reason that cause a problem?

Comment: `video-express` is trying to connect to `mongodb:27017` which should be `mongo:27017` because that's the name of the container. The first error (`ECONNREFUSED`) is probably related to MongoDB still starting up while you try to connect to it.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I changed the MongoDB part, I still received the same error. On the mongo-express page, I can see now admin is added, so I think mongo and mongo express themselves are working fine. However, I don't know how I got the connection or other sections wrong.